# POSTGRES : Add a constraint over rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a card table where I need to have a constraint, when a user has a card in ACTIVE or LOCKED state a new card shouldn't be created.

```
CREATE TABLE card
(cardId int,
userId int,
cardState varchar(255));
```

I tried exploring exclusion using **gist exclusion** and **partial unique index** but couldn't make any progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use `trigger` for that purpose.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik: No need for, too complex for such a simple thing as a conditional unique constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a conditional unique constraint/index:

```
CREATE TABLE card
(cardId int,
userId int,
cardState varchar(255)); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u_user_id_card_state ON card(userId) WHERE cardState IN('ACTIVE','LOCKED');

INSERT INTO card(cardid, userid, cardstate) VALUES(1,1, 'ACTIVE');

INSERT INTO card(cardid, userid, cardstate) VALUES(1,1, 'ACTIVE'); -- fails

INSERT INTO card(cardid, userid, cardstate) VALUES(1,1, 'LOCKED'); -- fails

INSERT INTO card(cardid, userid, cardstate) VALUES(1,1, 'something else'); -- works
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I was making the index on combination of userId and state. CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u_user_id_card_state ON card(userId) WHERE cardState IN('ACTIVE','LOCKED'); which is why it didn't work.